# JQuery UI Selectable plugin: Make scroll bar not selectable when div overflows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div that's set to `overflow: auto;`. This contents of this div are selectable (using jQuery UI).

When the div overflows and a scrollbar appears, the scrollbar itself becomes selectable so scrolling doesn't work well. In FF/Chrome, I can scroll the div but I get the selectable outline. In Safari, the scroll bar won't engage at all since the click is picked up by selectable's handler.

Is there a selector I can use to add the scrollbar to the 'cancel' items list? Or any other way to prevent the scroll bar from being selectable?

Here's a code snippet of how I'm configuring my selectable div:

```
$(".mySelectable").selectable( {
    cancel: '.myButton, .notSelectable',
    filter: '.rowSelectable',
    selecting: function(event, ui){
        handleSelection(ui.selecting);
    },
    selected: function(event, ui) {
        handleSelected(ui.selected);
    },
    unselected: function(event, ui) {
        handleUnselected(ui.unselected);
    }
});
```

My HTML looks like:

```
<div class="mySelectable"> <!-- set to auto overflow -->
    <div class="myButton">I can't be selected</div>
    <div class="rowSelectable">I am a selectable row</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Ideally, I'm looking for something that I can add to the 'cancel' option which helps skip the scroll bar.

Comment: That depends on what you have inside of the `div` and how you're getting the `focus` actions. Can you post some code and a little more description?

Comment: Added code. What do you mean by "getting the focus"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

D'oh! Solution was simple -- add another div and not have it's overflow set.
So, the html becomes:

```
    <div class="wrapperDiv"> <!-- set to auto overflow -->
        <div class="mySelectable"> <!-- NOT set to overflow -->
            <div class="myButton">I can't be selected</div>
            <div class="rowSelectable">I am a selectable row</div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: To clarify, "not set to overflow" means set overflow: visible;

Comment: To clarify, "not set to overflow" means Not to set overflow property :) and it works

Comment: The solution has a bug: after scrolling to the bottom the items stop being selectable.